# Confirming Markdown Files

Tags: php, file-upload, mime-types, markdown

I'm working on a PHP web application which will accept Markdown files as a file input.

How should I make sure that Markdown and only Markdown files are being uploaded?

I think I should check more than the extension... maybe the mime type?

If so, what is that mime type?

Comment: Mime type would be a good start, but like any uploaded user files, also a good idea to check the content where possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

extension and mime type are same.

check UTF-8, you can block any binary files (image files, etc)

```
if ($markdown !== iconv("UTF-8", "UTF-8//IGNORE", $markdown)) {
```

if an user uploads a HTML or JavaScript file, it is not what you want, but it match the Markdown syntax. so PHP can't identify it.

Comment: Extension and mimetype are only the same on Windows.